# Why would Batman discard his disruptor?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

During the chase sequence in which Batman reveals himself during *The Dark Knight Rises*, there is a sequence when Batman uses a pump action disruptor weapon against Bane's getaway motorcade.

[image]

Moments after we see how useful this weapon is, a rookie cop shoots the weapon, disabling it:

[image]

The next part really puzzles me: *Batman throws the weapon down*.

It's obviously useless to him: but he's just given over a piece of evidence to them, which seems hugely uncharacteristic of the Nolan-Verse Batman SOP.

During *The Dark Knight*, his Tumbler even self-destructs after the Batpod is ejected, presumably to destroy any evidence that would link the vehicle to Wayne Enterprises.

[image]

I realize that he gives a boy a surveillance device during *Batman Begins*, but I think given the police attention these are different circumstances.

I also accept that the moment is funny, and understand it to be a nod to the audience that Nolan isn't going to let batman use his 'gadgets' to pull victory out of his a$!%hole, like times of yore...

[image]

But I still don't understand why he would throw the device down. It just seems incredibly sloppy for what has been typically methodical execution.

**Does anyone have any insight on this?**

Comment: Holy S**t. Just realized by watching the 2nd Gif that the Batpod is made by the two *front* wheels. Mind = Blown.

Comment: Does he actually throw the weapon down, or merely reattach it to his belt or the Batpod? The gifs you posted don't show him throwing down the weapon, and I'm not in a position to pull out my DVD and watch it right now.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Wow, never realized that myself. :D

Comment: Somewhat related [tv trope: main/throwaway guns](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThrowAwayGuns), but it's also very common in movies for characters to just throw away a gun after using it in one scene - particularly action/horror films. "Sweet, we got through this one battle, won't need this gun anymore!"

Comment: @JamesSheridan: Yes, he quite explicitly *throws* it away from him, like he's throwing one of his toys out of the pram!

Comment: @phantom42: I'm fully aware of the disposable gun tendency in action films, but I think you're missing the point... Batman's technology is linked to Wayne Enterprises, and previously they've made a point of making sure that connection remains hidden..

Comment: In that case, I would have to assume it is simply an oversight on Nolan's part. One could ret-con a self-destructing gun, but that's about it.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: " I'm not in a position to pull out my DVD and watch it right now" - then you *get* into position. This isn't amateur hour, James, this is *Stack Exchange* damnit.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14998/why-would-batman-discard-his-disruptor

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Please don't cross-post the same question on multiple SE sites.